# Find the second derivative of a log likelihood function

Tags: r, regression

I'm interested in finding the values of the second derivatives of the log-likelihood function for logistic regression with respect to all of my m predictor variables.

Essentially I want to make a vector of m *∂*<sup>2</sup>L/*∂**β*<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup> values where j goes from 1 to m.

I believe the second derivative should be -Σ<sub>i=1</sub><sup>*n*</sup> x<sub>ij</sub><sup>2</sup>(e<sup>*x*<sub>*i*</sub>*β*</sup>)/((1+e<sup>*x*<sub>*i*</sub>*β*</sup>)<sup>2</sup>) and I am trying to code it in R. I did something dumb when trying to code it and was wondering if there was some sort of sapply function I could use to do it more easily.

Here's the code I tried (I know the sum in the for loop doesn't really do anything, so I wasn't sure how to sum those values).

```
  for (j in 1:m)
  {
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
      d2.l[j] <- -1*(sum((x.center[i,j]^2)*(exp(logit[i])/((1 + exp(logit[i])^2)))))
    }
  }
```

And logit is just a vector consisting of *Xβ* if that's not clear.

Comment: This is a pure programming question as far as I can tell and should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: Perhaps you could try the `deriv` function from the stats package, and then iterate per delta?

Comment: Or, why not derive the equation for the second derivative yourself? (I don't know too much about stats)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hazy on the maths (and it's hard to read latex) but purely on the programming side, if `logit` is a vector with indices `i`=1,...,n and `x.center` is a `nxm` matrix:

```
for (j in 1:m)
   dt.l[j] <- -sum( x.center[,j]^2 * exp(logit)/(1+exp(logit))^2 )
```

where the `sum` sums over `i`.

If you want to do it "vector-ish", you can take advantage of the fact that if you do `matrix * vector` (your `x.center * exp(logit)/...`) this happens column-wise in R which suits your equation:

```
-colSums(x.center^2 * exp(logit)/(1+exp(logit))^2)
```

For what it's worth, although the latter is "slicker", I will often use the explicit loop (as with the first example), purely for readability. Or else when I come back in a month's time I get very confused about my `i`s and `j`s and what is being summed over when.